# How to delete a cell from jTable by pressing DELETE key?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a code like below. I want to delete cell by pressing a delete key. How can I do that? And I also want to add delete button in that field.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -250883760398754970L;
private final LinkedList<Product> list= new LinkedList<Product>();
    private final LinkedList<Boolean> checkList = new LinkedList<Boolean>();
    public void addItem(Product customer) {
    list.add(customer);
    checkList.add(false);
    fireTableDataChanged();

}
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
        return 6;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return list.size();

}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Object obj = null;

    if(columnIndex==4)
       {
    setTotal(list.get(rowIndex));
    }
             switch (columnIndex){
        case 0: obj= list.get(rowIndex).getCode() ;break;
        case 1: obj=list.get(rowIndex).getDescription(); break;
        case 2: obj=list.get(rowIndex).getQuantity();break;
        case 3: obj=list.get(rowIndex).getPrice();break;            
        case 4: obj=list.get(rowIndex).getTotal();break;
    }
    return obj;
}
    @Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {

    switch(arg0){
    case 0: case 1: return String.class; 
    case 2: return Integer.class; 
    case 3: case 4: return Double.class;
    }

    return super.getColumnClass(arg0);
}
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    boolean isCellEditable = false;
    switch(arg1){
    case 2: case 3: isCellEditable= true;break;
    default: isCellEditable= false;break;
    }
    return isCellEditable;
    //return super.isCellEditable(arg0, arg1);
}


@Override

public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    System.out.println("Value seted" +arg0 + arg1 + arg2);


    switch(arg2){
    case 0: break;
    case 1: break;
    case 2: list.get(arg1).setQuantity((Integer)arg0);             setTotal(list.get(arg1)); break;
    case 3: list.get(arg1).setPrice((Double)arg0); setTotal(list.get(arg1));break;          
    case 4: list.get(arg1).setTotal((Double)arg0);break;



       //case 0: checkList.set(arg1, (Boolean)arg0);break;
       default:break;
    }
    //list.get(arg1).setTotal((Double)arg0);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}



public LinkedList<Product> getList() {
    LinkedList<Product> temp = new LinkedList<Product>();
    int index=-1;
    for(Boolean isSelected:checkList){
        index++;
        if(isSelected){
            temp.add(list.get(index));
        }
    }
    return temp;
}


public void setTotal(Product product){
    Double total = 0.0d;
    total = product.getQuantity ()* product.getPrice();
    product.setTotal(total);

}
```

Is it possible with this code? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to bind the delete key to the table.

Take a look at [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

```
InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "delete");
actionMap.put("delete", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       // Note, you can use getSelectedRows() and/or getSelectedColumns
       // to get all the rows/columns that have being selected
       // and simply loop through them using the same method as
       // described below.
       // As is, it will only get the lead selection
       int row = table.getSelectedRow();
       int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
       if (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
           row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
           col = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(col);
           table.getModel().setValueAt(null, row, col);
       }
    }
});
```

This is just an example.  You could delete an entire row with the same idea, so long as your table model supported it.

Comment: minus 1 for the non-functional deletion/compiler error at `setValueAt`

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Then I guess you're the only one. What error are you getting? I use this exact code in many production systems, so any issues you're having have to be with how you're using it

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza So, you're basically saying "I got an error so it must be everybody else's fault!" You're unlikely to find any answer which directly fulfils you requirements exactly and the provided answer is contextual to the question asked.  However, I use this type of functionality all the time, normally to delete rows

Comment: The error is as follows:
`The method setValueAt(Object, int, int) in the type TableModel is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, null)`. The code line should be `table.getModel().setValueAt(null, row, col);`
Still love your contributions, MadProgrammer :)

Answer (score 0):

The last row in the example above should be:

```
table.getModel().setValueAt(null, row, col);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works with sorted [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)s that are in `single selection` mode. Thanks to [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) for the key bindings.

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();

String deleteAction = "delete";
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0),
        deleteAction);
actionMap.put(deleteAction, new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent deleteEvent)
    {
        if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1)
        {
            tableModel.removeRow(table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()));
        }
    }
});
```